# Navbar in HTML/CSS not functioning properly

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am new to website design, and there are a few flaws in my navbar that I cannot fix.

1. I cannot get the navbar to center properly.
2. When the screen resolution changes, the list overflows into the next line.
3. there is 1 list element that is sized differently and I cannot seem to figure out why.

Here is the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/b02nm6ae/#update

CSS:

```
.nav_wrapper {
z-index: 9999;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
min-width: 50px;
}

.nav_wrapper ul {
display: block;
position: relative;
position: fixed;
/* fixes automatic values set by ul */
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}

.nav_wrapper ul li {
list-style: none;
display: list-item;
background-color: #993300;
float: left;
}

/* hides the submenu by default */
.nav_wrapper ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
}

/* makes the sub menu appear on hover over list element */
.nav_wrapper ul li:hover > .sub_nav1 {
display: list-item;
list-style: none;
}

/* lists the list items on top of one another */
.nav_wrapper ul .sub_nav1 li {
float: none;
position: relative;
}

.nav_wrapper ul li a{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 12px;
}

.nav_wrapper li a:hover{
color: #000;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* Dropdown Menu arrow */
.nav_wrapper ul li > a:after { 
    content: '\25BE';           
}

.nav_wrapper ul li > a:only-child:after { 
    content: '';
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<!-- NAV -->
<div class="nav_wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calandar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul class="sub_nav1">
            <li><a href="#">The Pastor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Byzantines</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mass Times</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
<div>

<!-- SECTION 1 -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you paste your HTML in the body of your question? More specifically, can you provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard The jsfiddle had the html in it, and it also showed the problems, but I uploaded the html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you float the `li` then centering becomes problematical. In these instances, it's often preferred to use `display:inline-block` and center then by applying `text-align:center` to the parent `ul`.

This does have a `white-space` downside but there are methods around that, one of which (font-size) I have used here.

As for the single element with the greater height...that was caused by the pseudo-element...so slapped a quick patch over it. Frankly, I would be applying a class to the parent `li` and using a pseudo-element on the `li` but that's another debate entirely.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #CCCCFF;
}
.nav_wrapper ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  /* remove whitespace */
}
.nav_wrapper ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #993300;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* font-size reset */
}
/* hides the submenu by default */

.nav_wrapper ul ul {
  display: none;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
/* makes the sub menu appear on hover over list element */

.nav_wrapper ul li:hover > .sub_nav1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
/* lists the list items on top of one another */

.nav_wrapper ul .sub_nav1 li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav_wrapper ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 12px;
}
.nav_wrapper li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
/* Dropdown Menu arrow */

.nav_wrapper ul> li > a:after {
  content: '\25BE';
  line-height: 0;
}
.nav_wrapper ul li > a:only-child:after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Calendar</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>

      <ul class="sub_nav1">
        <li><a href="#">The Pastor</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Byzantines</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Mass Times</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
```

Comment: Ah, I seen that in another post but I was applying the inline-block element to the parent ul and not to the li elements..... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well I notice that if I set a 25 pixel height to

```
.nav_wrapper ul li a
```

that removes the extra space for example..

```
.nav_wrapper ul li a{
    height:25px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b02nm6ae/9/